# Есть ли в русском языке глагол «распандирить»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, глаголы

Такое слово присутствовало в лексиконе моей бабушки (родилась в 1909 году в Новгороде; в тридцатые — сороковые жила в Киеве(?), в Глазове; с 1947 года — в Эстонии).
Употреблялось оно, в основном, в значении "распороть". Жили небогато, поэтому старые вещи частенько перешивались, перекраивались, комбинировались.

Я привыкла к этому слову и нередко использую. Но в словарях его нет.
Друзья, встречался ли вам этот глагол — где и в каком значении? Поделитесь, пожалуйста, информацией.

Answer (score 1):

Слово с похожим корнем и смыслом имеется в словаре.
Язык блатных. Язык мафиози [Энциклопедический синонимический словарь. В двух томах]
Хоменко Олег Борисович.

РАСПАНАХАТЬ — раскроить. Также — разорвать платье (в знач. одежду). См. Декольтировать.
РАСПАНДОХАТЬ — разрезать. См. Попис?рить. Также — уничтожить кого-либо, что-либо. См. На смарку пустить.
РАСПАНДЮХИ — пеленки. Также — распашонки.

https://law.wikireading.ru/hraHDnM4lp